# Application hangs randomly while opening file for reading

Tags: c++, windows

My application hangs randomly while opening a file for reading, present on network shared location. I am using _wopen to open the file. The same thing work most of the times but hangs a few times.

What are common causes for _wopen to hang, if any?

Comment: If you open a file from a network location, you're latency is bound to the network's performance. If network congestion spikes, so might your latency.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response  François Andrieux. I understand your point, but I think network congestion is not the case here as I have even waited for 2hrs just _wopen to execute. Does _wopen need to take any lock, which would have been already taken by some other thread. Can this be the case.

Comment: Try navigating to that file manually in the file browser. Check if it asks you for a password. If it does, providing it will likely unblock your application.

Comment: Do you open the file for writing? If you do, yes it might wait for a write lock on it.

Comment: The problem is network related - a misconfiguration of some form, not (necessarily) congestion. The network connection is being lost somehow during communication between hosts. There are many possible causes, such as DNS misconfiguration (affects ability to establish connections between machines), credentials issue (machine hosting the shared drive doesn't recognise your machine, or the user running the program). You'll need to sniff network packets (e.g. using wireshark) to get a pointer to the problem. Symptoms are intermittent, so you may need to do that repeatedly or over a time period.